# Parity operator for a general $N\times N$ Hamiltonian

Tags: hamiltonian, parity, matrix-elements, tight-binding

Assume I've a $N\times N$ tight-binding Hamiltonian that depends on spatial coordinates $k=(k_x, k_y)$; it holds
$$ H(k)|\psi_k\rangle = E_k |\psi_k\rangle \quad  .$$

Now I want to find the parity operator $P$ such that I can check the parity of the eigenfunctions at given $(k_x, k_y)$ as
$$ P |\psi(k_x, k_y)\rangle = \pm 1 |\psi(k_x, k_y)\rangle  \quad .$$

How to properly find $P$? Is it the correct way to get $P$ as transformation matrix by $P H(k_x, k_y)P^{-1} = H(-k_x, -k_y)$ and additionally ask for the commutator to be $[H,P]=0$.

What is the general (mathematical) strategy of finding $P$ for a (tight-binding) Hamiltonian $H$?